Syncing Magento 2.4 to Mailchimp using Ebizmarts module
I am syncing the Magento 2.4 to my Mailchimp account using the Ebizmart extension as per Mailchimp recommendation.
My issue is that, as soon as I enable the module, the sync starts but it is syncing all the shop's contacts (instead of the subscribers Only) from Magento to Mailchimps!
I don't know how to stop this and change it to syncing the subscribers only.
I checked all the Ebizmart options under its configuration but I can't find such as option to only sync the subscribers and not all contacts, I also spoke to mailchimps and they advised to disable the module until I find the solution.
